# Custom action on complete()

Tags: vim

In Atom IDE, there is a nice feature called "snippets" which allows to insert user-defined code blocks by typing a certain sequence of characters:

[image]

I made a small example according to Vim documentation:

```
inor <F5> <C-R>=ShowPopup()<CR>

func! ShowPopup()
        call complete(col('.'), ['inc', 'main'])
        retu ''
endf
```

[image]

Now I want the `main` item to become `int main() {}` when I select that item in popup menu and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Insert mode. Is this possible with built-in Vim functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. It just require some work. Work that usually ends up in ... snippet plugins. So yeah, plugins are written from built-in functionalities.

The idea is that the completion function triggers an event which is used to do the actual replacement. See for instance this Q/A on vi.SE where I explore how to write a more dynamic completion function: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/dynamic-completion